# Wiggling shapes over an image with p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Here is the image:

[image: Dorothy]

I'm using p5.js to draw random circles over an image. I have the code below that makes the circles appear and I wanted. However, I want all the dots to wiggle a bit as well. I'm having trouble figuring this aspect out. I appreciate any tips! Thanks

```js
let img;
let smallPoint, largePoint;
let fr = 30;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage('images/face.png');
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(720, 800);
    let cvn = createCanvas(1000, 1000);
    let x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
    let y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
    cvn.position(x,y);
    smallPoint = 5;
    largePoint = 20;
    noStroke();
    background(255);
    image(img, 0, 0, 720, 800);
    img.loadPixels();
    frameRate(fr);
}

function draw() {
    let pointillize = map(mouseX, 0, width, smallPoint, largePoint);
    let x = floor(random(img.width));
    let y = floor(random(img.height));
    let pix = img.get(x, y);
    fill(pix);
    ellipse(x, y, pointillize, pointillize);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want you have to change the setup. You have to redraw all the points in every frame.

Create a point per frame and store the point to an array:

```js
points = []

function draw() {
    let pointillize = map(mouseX, 0, width, smallPoint, largePoint);
    let x = random(img.width);
    let y = random(img.height);
    let pix = img.get(x, y);
    points.push( {x: x, y: y, color: pix, size: pointillize});

    // [...]
```

Draw the image in every frame and draw all the points on top of it:

```js
    // [...]

    for(let i= 0; i < points.length; i++ ) {
        let p = points[i];
        fill(p.color);
        ellipse(p.x, p.y, p.size, p.size);
    }
}
```

To achieve a "wiggle" effect, I recommend to use the [`sin()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/sin) function, to compute an offset and to use [`millis()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/millis) to change the offset by time.

Create a random scale (`sx`, `sy`) and offset (`dx`, `dx`) for each point:

```js
let dx = random();
let dy = random();
let sx = random();
let sy = random();
points.push( {x: x, y: y, color: pix, size: pointillize, dx: dx, dy: dy, sx: sx, sy: sy});
```

Compute the wiggle effect dependent on time (`t`). In the following the wiggle depends on th tenth of a second (`millis() * 0.01`) and the amount is from -3 to 3:

```js
let t =  millis() * 0.01;
```

```js
let x = p.x + sin(PI * p.dx + t * p.sx) * 3;
let y = p.y + sin(PI * p.dy + t * p.sy) * 3;
ellipse(x, y, p.size, p.size);
```

See the example:

```js
let img;
let smallPoint, largePoint;
let fr = 100;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/parrot_image.jpg');
}

function setup() {
    let cvn = createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
    let x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
    let y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
    cvn.position(x,y);
    smallPoint = 5;
    largePoint = 20;
    img.loadPixels();
    frameRate(fr);
}

points = []
function draw() {
    let pointillize = map(mouseX, 0, width, smallPoint, largePoint);
    let x = random(img.width), y = random(img.height);
    let pix = img.get(x, y);
    let dx = random(), dy = random(), sx = random(), sy = random();
    points.push( {x: x, y: y, color: pix, size: pointillize, dx: dx, dy: dy, sx: sx, sy: sy});

    noStroke();
    background(255);
    image(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    let t =  millis() * 0.01;
    for(let i= 0; i < points.length; i++ ) {
        let p = points[i];
        fill(p.color);
        let x = p.x + sin(PI * p.dx + t * p.sx) * 3;
        let y = p.y + sin(PI * p.dy + t * p.sy) * 3;
        ellipse(x, y, p.size, p.size);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot! Sorry for the late reply, had a busy week

Comment: @medanlee If you found the answer helpful, please accept the answer provided by Rabbid76, since they have put in a lot of effort. Thank you!